# How to fix Segmentation Fault in linked list

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I'm getting a segmentation fault error that I don't know how to fix. List.cpp and List.hpp are bigger, but I added just what I'm using in main.cpp. Here is the code:

### List.hpp

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Node{
    int _value;
    Node *_next;
};

struct List{
    Node *_head;
    int _size;

    List();
    void insert(int value);
    void print();
};

#endif
```

### List.cpp

```
#include "List.hpp"

List::List(){
    _size = 0;
    _head = nullptr;
}

void List::insert(int value){
    Node* node;
    node->_value = value;
    node->_next = _head;
    _head = node;
}

void List::print(){
    Node* head = _head;
    if (_size > 0){
        while(head){
            std::cout << head->_value << " ";
            head = head->_next;
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.hpp"

int main(){
    List *L = new List();
    int N=0;
    std::cout << "type the N value"<< std::endl;
    std::cin >> N;

    for(int i=0; i<=N; i++){
        L->insert(i);
    }

    L->print();
    delete L;
    return 0;
}
```

### console

```
▶ g++ -std=c++14 -Wall main.cpp List.cpp -o main && ./main out
List.cpp: In member function ‘void List::insert(int)’:
List.cpp:10:15: warning: ‘node’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   10 |  node->_value = value;
      |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
type the N value
3
[1]    13247 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./main out
```

I actually don't know how to debug it either (I'm using VS Code), so I have no idea about what is happening with the variables that are being created on the stack and on the heap.

Comment: It happens when you try to access an invalid memory address. Maybe you are not allocating memory before using it, or you are accessing memory that your program is not allowed to.

Comment: The compiler is telling the problem. ```node``` is uninitialized pointer. What is it pointing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error(warning) message says, in the `insert` function you are doing:

```
Node* node;
```

But this simply declares a pointer that is not yet pointing to valid memory. Accessing members of the object such as `_value` pointed at by `node` will invoke undefined behavior. This can cause a segmentation fault. If you're unlucky, there won't be a segfault, and the program will break at some later point.

You need to allocate memory for a `Node` like this:

```
Node* node = new Node{};
```

In fact, the entire `insert` function could simply be:

```
void List::insert(int value) {
    _head = new Node{value, _head};  // allocate Node, initialize to
                                     // appropriate values, and link _head
}
```

---

Also, you should default initialize the members of `Node` like this:

```
struct Node{
    int _value{};
    Node *_next = nullptr;
};
```

---

Also, there seems to be no need to allocate memory for a `List` in `main`:

```
List *L = new List();
```

Instead, you can simply have a `List` object like this:

```
List L{};
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the member function `insert` you are using an uninitialized pointer node

```
void List::insert(int value){
    Node* node;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
    node->_value = value;
    node->_next = _head;
    _head = node;
}
```

that has an indeterminate value and trying to access memory using this pointer that results in undefined behavior.

You have to allocate a node that will be pointed to by the pointer and inserted in the list.

Also you forgot to increase the size of the list.

But I would like to point to some drawbacks of the implementation.

For starters do not use identifiers that start from underscore because according to the C++ Standard

> (3.2) — Each identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to
> the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

So such names will confuse readers of your code.

The structure `Node` should be a private or protected data member of the structure `List`. The user shall not have a direct access to the structure Node. It is an implementation detail.

There is no sense to allocate an object of the type List dynamically.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the list can be implemented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class List
{
protected:
    struct Node
    {
        int value;
        Node *next;
    } *head = nullptr;

    size_t n = 0;

public: 
    List() = default;
    ~List() { clear(); }
    
    //  These special member functions you can define yourself if you will want
    List( const List & ) = delete;
    List & operator =( const List & ) = delete;
    

    void insert( int value );

    size_t size() const { return n; }
    
    void clear()
    {
        while ( head ) delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
        n = 0;
    }
    
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const List &list )
    {
        for ( Node *current = list.head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
        {
            os << current->value << " -> ";
        }
        
        return os << "null";
    }
};

void List::insert( int value )
{
    head = new Node { value, head };
    ++n;
}

int main() 
{
    const int N = 10;
    
    List list;
    
    for ( int i = N; i != 0; i-- )
    {
        list.insert( i );
    }
    
    std::cout << list << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> null
```